# how to add a button in the running activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I am very new to android development and I am having problem displaying a new button to a activity which has already run. I am using this tutorial http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html. Here they display Hello World in the new activity. I would like to add a button called "SKIP"! So that the user can go to a another new activity called Functions. How do I do that with the intent? My intent is already being used to display the string hello world! I am using android studio.
Appreciate any help thanks

Comment: You need to post the relevant code and where you are stuck. Also be more specific. Do you want to add the `Button` at runtime or add it in the xml?

Answer (score 0):

To create a button you need to go to your main XML file, add a button.  Then in your Activity create a onClick listener for the button.

When it comes to going to another activity you need to create a new Intent with

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Functions.class);
startActivity(intent)
```

Answer (score 0):

You would call your new activity with the following snippet within the `OnClickListener` of your button:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Functions.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

And define your `Functions` class in your AndroidManifest.xml file similar to what the originally defined Activity is defined as.  But you should only have one launcher Activity.